# advanced search query laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, search, laravel-5

In my website i need to provide a search option where user can search for different product. Now i want if search key match with product display it and along with display some suggestion contain with that search keyword separated by space.

```
list($type,$search) = explode(":", $key);
$searchValues = preg_split('/\s+/', $search, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

ProductDetail::join('product_brands','product_details.brand_id','product_brands.id')
              ->select('brand_name as manufacturer','product_availability as isInStock','product_details.*','product_price as displayPrice')
              ->where(function ($q) use ($searchValues,$search) {
                    $q->where('product_name', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                    foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
                      $q->orWhere('product_name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
                    }
                })->paginate(5);
```

Now problem with this result is, it does't display according to **best/first match**. so user can't find what they are looking for in the list of other suggestions.

**So how to get best matched order?**

[View Live Demo](http://purvipharma.co.in/brand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is some sort of weighted search.  If you take a look at this package you can see some example MySQL queries it generates:  https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable

Scroll to the "result" section where it shows the resulting queries it produces.  That will help you weight your results on best match. You can also look into [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout) if you have deeper search needs.

This is the example query I was referring to, where this package was used to search users like `Sed neque labore` :

```
select `users`.*, 

-- If third parameter is set as true, it will check if the column starts with the search
-- if then it adds relevance * 30
-- this ensures that relevant results will be at top
(case when first_name LIKE 'Sed neque labore%' then 300 else 0 end) + 

-- For each column you specify makes 3 "ifs" containing 
-- each word of the search input and adds relevace to 
-- the row

-- The first checks if the column is equal to the word,
-- if then it adds relevance * 15
(case when first_name LIKE 'Sed' || first_name LIKE 'neque' || first_name LIKE 'labore' then 150 else 0 end) + 

-- The second checks if the column starts with the word,
-- if then it adds relevance * 5
(case when first_name LIKE 'Sed%' || first_name LIKE 'neque%' || first_name LIKE 'labore%' then 50 else 0 end) + 

-- The third checks if the column contains the word, 
-- if then it adds relevance * 1
(case when first_name LIKE '%Sed%' || first_name LIKE '%neque%' || first_name LIKE '%labore%' then 10 else 0 end) + 

-- Repeats with each column
(case when last_name LIKE 'Sed' || last_name LIKE 'neque' || last_name LIKE 'labore' then 150 else 0 end) + 
(case when last_name LIKE 'Sed%' || last_name LIKE 'neque%' || last_name LIKE 'labore%' then 50 else 0 end) +
(case when last_name LIKE '%Sed%' || last_name LIKE '%neque%' || last_name LIKE '%labore%' then 10 else 0 end) + 

(case when bio LIKE 'Sed' || bio LIKE 'neque' || bio LIKE 'labore' then 30 else 0 end) + 
(case when bio LIKE 'Sed%' || bio LIKE 'neque%' || bio LIKE 'labore%' then 10 else 0 end) + 
(case when bio LIKE '%Sed%' || bio LIKE '%neque%' || bio LIKE '%labore%' then 2 else 0 end) + 

(case when email LIKE 'Sed' || email LIKE 'neque' || email LIKE 'labore' then 75 else 0 end) + 
(case when email LIKE 'Sed%' || email LIKE 'neque%' || email LIKE 'labore%' then 25 else 0 end) + 
(case when email LIKE '%Sed%' || email LIKE '%neque%' || email LIKE '%labore%' then 5 else 0 end) 

as relevance 
from `users` 
group by `id` 

-- Selects only the rows that have more than
-- the sum of all attributes relevances and divided by 4
-- Ej: (20 + 5 + 2) / 4 = 6.75
having relevance > 6.75 

-- Orders the results by relevance
order by `relevance` desc
```

Comment: Thank you for this help.I will try to implement this.I really looking like this package